# Spring Security LDAP Configuration BeanCreationException on app server startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap

I'm trying to hook up my Spring 3.1 app to my in-house Zimbra LDAP server.  I'm doing something likely very stupid and I cannot see the problem.  I'm certain there could be issues with the group and user base and filter terms I defined, but that shouldn't be causing a BeanCreationException on app server startup, should it?  I could use another pair of eyes...

The short version of the exception:

"Can't convert an LdapAuthenticationProvider to required type AuthenticationProvider for property providers[0]"

The full exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'parent'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#16': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'providers'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider] for property 'providers[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

The relevant Spring configuration file entry:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:ldap-authentication-provider
        group-search-filter="member={0}"
        group-search-base="ou=groups"
        user-search-base="ou=people"
        user-search-filter="uid={0}"
    />        
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:ldap-server url="ldap://<correct IP and port>" manager-dn="uid=zimbra,cn=admins,cn=zimbra" manager-password="<private>" />
```

Thanks for any insights you can provide!

Comment: It may have nothing to do with the exception, but the parameter assignment `user-search-base="ou=people"` may be missing the right-most portion of the DN, unless your naming context actually is `"ou=people"`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is a mismatch between your included Spring libraries.
You need to make sure your Spring Security LDAP libraries match your other Spring Security library versions.

For instance:

```
spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-ldap-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
```